# Insert Image to Word Doc File From SQL Server

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I want to export image which is displayed on web page. This image is stored in Sql image data type. While displaying image I am converting the image to Base64String.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(imgPhoto)
```

While exporting page, image is not displaying in word document file.

I can not store image on the server because of security reason.
below code is for export to word file.

```
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Test.doc")
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word "
    Response.Charset = ""
    Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)

    ' Create a form to contain the grid
    ControlID.RenderControl(htmlWrite)

    Dim stringWrite1 As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim htmlWrite1 As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite1)

    ' Create a form to contain the grid
    ImageLogo.RenderControl(htmlWrite1)

    Response.Write(stringWrite1.ToString() & stringWrite.ToString())
    Response.[End]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You really aren't creating a Word document, just rendering the HTML to a word MIME type. I don't believe word supports the data:image definition since that is much newer than the pre-2007 word format. Instead, try the OpenXML SDK. Although it creates Word 2007+ documents only, most people can view them. The OpenXML SDK will enable you to create a real word doc and create an image from the binary image data.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx